# Dockerized Vue app - hot reload does not work

Tags: docker, vue.js, docker-compose, dockerfile, hot-reload

Dockerized Vue app loads normally to the browser, when applying changes to the code are not reflected without refresh.

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:14-alpine

# make the 'app' folder the current working directory
WORKDIR /app

# copy 'package.json'
COPY package.json .

# install project dependencies
RUN npm install

# copy project files and folders to the current working directory (i.e. 'app' folder)
#COPY . .


EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["npm", "run", "serve"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.9'
services:
  frontend:
    container_name: 'frontend'
    build: ./
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
      - /app/node_modules
    environment:
      - HOST=0.0.0.0
      - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "project",
  "version": "1.6.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "vue": "^2.6.12",
    "vue-axios": "^3.2.2",
    "vuetify": "2.3.18",
    "vuex": "^3.6.0",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^4.5.10",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^4.5.11",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "^4.5.10",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest": "^4.5.10",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "^4.5.10",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^4.5.10",
    "@vue/eslint-config-prettier": "^6.0.0",
    "@vue/test-utils": "1.1.2",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",        
    "node-sass": "^5.0.0",
    "sass": "^1.32.4",
    "sass-loader": "^10.1.1",
    "vuetify-loader": "^1.6.0",
    "webpack": "^4.46.0"
  }
}
```

When I'm running the project locally, the hot reload works great!

Any idea what might be the issue on the docker?

**EDIT** Since this is a docker for development purposes, I have tried as well to remove the `COPY . .` without result.

Comment: Can you try to remove the `/app/node_modules` volume and see if hot-reload works?

Comment: Tried it, no result...

Comment: I don't think you need Docker for this.  Can you use plain Node, without Docker?  Since that will have direct access to your host filesystem without the isolation Docker provides, things like live reloading should work much better.

Comment: Is your dev server running behind a reverse proxy and HTTPS? Which OS is hosting your Docker engine?

Comment: @DavidMaze The idea behind this docker is to be used from a team, since the project using specific versions of node and npm.

Comment: @James Not sure if it helps but the local front project hits a dev backend server which I need to be connected to VPN. This is on MACOS

Comment: There were older versions of Docker for MacOS that had issues with picking up file changes in the host OS when using bind mounts...are you running the latest Docker Desktop? If so, maybe try enabling VirtioFS in experimental features

Comment: @James Yeah docker is recently installed, I just tried the VirtioFS enabled without result.. When Im saving the new changes I see from terminal that rebuilds it but still the hot reload is not working..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After many days I managed to add hot reload by adding in the webpack configuration file this config:

```
devServer: {
      public: '0.0.0.0:8080'
    }
```

After digging to the official vue js repo, specifically to [serve.js](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/blob/dev/packages/%40vue/cli-service/lib/commands/serve.js#L30) file found the `public` option which:

> specify the public network URL for the HMR client

If you do not want to edit your webpack config, you can do this directly from docker-compose file in the command:

```
command: npm run serve -- --public 0.0.0.0:8080
```

Answer (score 6):

The issue can be also in your vue.config.js file.

```
    module.exports = defineConfig({
        configureWebpack: {
            entry: "./src/main.js",
            devServer: {
                hot: true,
            },
            watch: true,
            watchOptions: {
                ignored: /node_modules/,
                poll: 1000,
            },
        },
        transpileDependencies: true,
    });
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! Lost many hours trying to find a solution

Comment: It works on vue-cli@5.0.8 (see the other answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/75749024/5697539 )

Comment: Did this the trick on vue3 using docker. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your template looks very close to [this Docker Vue Hot-Reload template](https://github.com/Rehost-Startup/template-vue) that works fine.
The only difference is the `HOST=0.0.0.0` is set inside Dockerfile in the mentioned template. Maybe doing a fresh build would work.

PS: I created this template.

Comment: It's the same thing where you specify the env either in dockerfile or compose. I have tried as well so many new builds

Comment: https://vitejs.dev/config/#server-host Could you try manually specifying host at the time of starting Vue?
"vite --host" should work I think

Comment: Project using Webpack and not Vite

Comment: Okay, I've encountered this in React. Someone solved the webpack-Docker issue here https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/11879#issuecomment-1070466261
You need to run setup.js file once before starting the hot-reload server. It worked for me for React. I think its worth a try for Vue

Answer (score 0):

Solution for Vue3 when using vue-cli and docker-compose is passing the public url without port to the serve command from docker-compose

```
command: yarn serve --public http://localhost
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on Anton Lavrenchuk's answer, I can confirm that the following works on @vue/cli@5.0.8 on an Ubuntu docker container. I did a line by line ablation and it seems that only the `watch` parameter was unnecessary.

```js
const { defineConfig } = require('@vue/cli-service')
module.exports = defineConfig({
  transpileDependencies: true,  
  publicPath: '/myapp',
  configureWebpack: {
    entry: "./src/main.js",  
    devServer: {
      hot: true,
      port: 8081,
      host: '0.0.0.0',
    },    
    watchOptions: {
      ignored: /node_modules/,
      poll: 1000,
    }
  }  
})
```

The `host: 0.0.0.0` and `port: 8081` are to publish to the localhost from the container. Note that container has to be run with the correct ports exposed, so something like `docker run -it -p 8080-8090:8080-8090 -v local/path/to/vueapp:/home/vueapp` IMAGEID bash` would work.

With the `vue.config.js` as above, just the humble `npm run serve` works with hot reload.

Answer (score 0):

In my case browserlist was no updated
I have used below to update , then hot reload started working

```
 npx update-browserslist-db@latest
```

and running it with

```
npm run serve -- --public 0.0.0.0:8080
```